# Assign value of array to index of another array in c++

Tags: c++, matlab, c++11, c++14

Hi I have seen in Matlab when you have two array like below, you can assign value of array one to index value of array two.

```
A= [11,12,13];
B=[1,2,3,2,1,3,1,2,3,1];
C=A(B);
C:11,12,13,12,11,13,11,12,13,11
```

How can I do that in c++ ?(for example with two c++ vector)
Best Regard

Comment: C++ doesn't have built-in vectorized computations. You'll have to write a loop.

Comment: @NPE Thanks for your answer, I have writing HPC code and need very fast solution, I think your solution is the last chance and I knew this method.
Do you have any solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With vectors you can do something like

```
std::vector<int> A = {11,12,13};
std::vector<int> B ={1,2,3,2,1,3,1,2,3,1};
std::vector<int> C;


for(auto index:B)
  C.push_back(A[index-1]);  //In the first iteration A[index-1] would be A[1-1] so A[0] i.e 11 will be pushed and so on
```

However there isn't any built in method to do that.

Comment: Adding a `C.reserve(B.size())` before the loop should speed up this code significantly.